# Restart Flink job without specifying savepoint ID

Tags: apache-flink

When I stop a Flink job, Flink generates a savepoint ID, e.g., `savepoint-b89571-cfb5fdc03a16` in the following example:

```
$ flink stop b895716d023b2e14e57888d120eedccb

Suspending job "b895716d023b2e14e57888d120eedccb" with a savepoint.
Savepoint completed. Path: file:/tmp/flink-savepoints-directory/savepoint-b89571-cfb5fdc03a16
```

I need to remember the ID, then use it to restart the job later:

```
$ flink run -s /tmp/flink-savepoints-directory/savepoint-b89571-cfb5fdc03a16 ...

Starting execution of program
Job has been submitted with JobID 3abf1469779428cdfa918a0e115f83c3
```

I feel this is not convenient and error-prone. Is there a way that I only specify the savepoint folder without caring about the savepoint ID? When restarting job with the folder, it automatically detects which savepoint to use. Maybe by default use the last savepoint, that is okay.